# Countdown using `while`

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop, countdown

I want to write code for a number countdown and want to celebrate with `"HAPPY NEW YEAR!"` using `while`.

```
def countdown(number)
  while number > 0
    puts "#{number} SECOND(S)!"
    number -= 1
  end
  puts "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
end
```

My code doesn't work.  What's wrong with this code?

**UPD** Failing test is below (moved here from comments by @mudasobwa):

```
describe '#countdown' do
  let(:countdown_output) { 
    "10 SECOND(S)!\n9 SECOND(S)!\n8 SECOND(S)!\n7 SECOND(S)!\n6 SECOND(S)!\n5 SECOND(S)!\n4 SECOND(S)!\n3 SECOND(S)!\n2 SECOND(S)!\n1 SECOND(S)!\n" 
  } 
  it "outputs '<n> SECOND(S)!' string to STDOUT for each count" do
    expect { countdown(10) }.to output(countdown_output).to_stdout
  end
  it 'returns HAPPY NEW YEAR!' do
    expect(countdown(12)).to eq "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
  end
end
```

Comment: is it better to use a range instead of a variable?

Comment: How is the code to be used?

Comment: sorry should have clarified...it executed correctly in IRB but won't pass the rspec written for it.  it has been raising exceptions.  I had the number at 10 when it is called.

Comment: @JustANoobie, what is rspec telling you?

Comment: @Dan Phillips describe '#countdown' do
    let(:countdown_output) { "10 SECOND(S)!\n9 SECOND(S)!\n8 SECOND(S)!\n7 SECOND(S)!\n6 SECOND(S)!\n5 SECOND(S)!\n4 SECOND(S)!\n3 SECOND(S)!\n2 SECOND(S)!\n1 SECOND(S)!\n" }

    it "outputs '<n> SECOND(S)!' string to STDOUT for each count" do
      expect { countdown(10) }.to output(countdown_output).to_stdout
    end

    it 'returns HAPPY NEW YEAR!' do
      expect(countdown(12)).to eq "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
    end
  end

Comment: I was trying to not send that in a jumbled mess...^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
expect(countdown(12)).to eq "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
```

Your function is *printing* HNY out to stdout, not *returning it*.

To fix the problem, `countdown` method should *return* the value instead:

```
def countdown(number)
  while number > 0
    puts "#{number} SECOND(S)!"
    number -= 1
  end
  # puts "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
  "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
end
```